# Delete selected row from Datagridview and simultaneously XML node upon delete button click

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview

At present the code deletes the row from Datgridview when user highlights entire row and selects delete button but it's not erased from XML file. So if I refresh page, the previously deleted row is still showing as grid view loads data from XML which it hasn't been deleted from.

Here is the code for the XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <Contacts>
    <FirstName>s</FirstName>
    <LastName>s</LastName>
    <Address>s</Address>
    <City>s</City>
    <Postcode>s</Postcode>
    <Number>s</Number>
  </Contacts>
  <Contacts>
    <FirstName>w</FirstName>
    <LastName>w</LastName>
    <Address>w</Address>
    <City>w</City>
    <Postcode>w</Postcode>
    <Number>w</Number>
  </Contacts>
  <Contacts>
    <FirstName>
    </FirstName>
    <LastName>
    </LastName>
    <Address>
    </Address>
    <City>
    </City>
    <Postcode>
    </Postcode>
    <Number>
    </Number>
  </Contacts>
  <Contacts>
    <FirstName>dkd</FirstName>
    <LastName>dkfskldf</LastName>
    <Address>asdfasf</Address>
    <City>dfs</City>
    <Postcode>dd</Postcode>
    <Number>dd</Number>
  </Contacts>
</NewDataSet>
```

Here is the code for the delete button event handler

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string Lname;

            DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection dgv_rc = this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows;

            foreach (DataGridViewRow dgv_r in dgv_rc)
            {
                this.dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(dgv_r);
            }

            if (dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
            {
                int selectedrowindex = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
                DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dataGridView1.Rows[selectedrowindex];
                Lname = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells["LastName"].Value);
                XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
                xdoc.Load("Contacts.xml");
                foreach (XmlNode xNode in xdoc.SelectNodes("Contacts"))
                    if (xNode.SelectSingleNode("LastName").InnerText == Lname) xNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(xNode);
                xdoc.Save("Contacts.xml");
                DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show(Lname + "deleted");
            }


        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I don't have time to fire up an IDE, but can you try swapping the two main blocks of code? It is possible that by calling `remove` on the grid, you can no longer access `SelectedCells` anymore. So try the `if` block first, then the `foreach` block.

Comment: It could have something to do with permissions to the file. Have you tried saving it to a different file / path and validate whether the changse were made?

Comment: I would also say that you have some other problems that will need to be addressed. Your `if` block **only** attempts to remove the **first** selected item, whereas you `foreach` block removed all of them. Further, you are searching your XML file arbitrarily by last name but the grid explicitly by index. If there are any items in the XML file with the same last name they will all get removed, even if they aren't deleted.

Comment: I switched around the two blocks and progress has been made as the program now deletes the row and also shows Last name of deleted row in message box. However it still isn't deleting from XML suggesting that there is an error there.

It's poor practice I'm using the last name as primary key however I wish to just get the program to function first & will possibly add in unique ID numbers for each element to iterate through & delete by instead.

Comment: When deleting 5 from a list 4,5,6; 6 becomes 5 causing indexing problems.  So When deleting always start from end of list a work towards the beginning.  So change foreach loop to a for loop : for(int row = dgv_c.Count() - 1; row >= 0; row--){ DataGridViewRow dgv_r = dgv_c[row];)